# Problems with Version Suffix in .net 8.0 with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0

I have the problem that I have an application in Visual Studio 2022 that runs on .net 8.0. The whole thing is implemented with VB.net.
Previously, the original version of the software was created with the .net Framework 4.8.

Now the whole thing has been migrated to .net 8.0 and since then I have had a version number problem.
The version numbers are no longer the same as before

0.0.1.0

rather

0.0.1.0+79272f70694e133e533d....

How do I get the version back to its original state?
All versions in the project, including all DLLs, are in the wrong format.
I would like to have the format 0.0.1.0 again, without the addition of the plus and the following number.

Thank you for your help

I already have everything possible in the .vbproj file

I have already set everything that was possible in the .vbproj file.
There is only one property for the version.
It is now kept to a minimum.

My vbproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>K6.Login</RootNamespace>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <Version>0.0.1.1</Version>
    <ApplicationManifest>My Project\app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Import Include="System.Data" />
    <Import Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="My Project\Resources.Designer.vb">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="My Project\Settings.Designer.vb">
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="My Project\Resources.resx">
      <CustomToolNamespace>My.Resources</CustomToolNamespace>
      <Generator>VbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Resources\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\K6.Admin\K6.Admin.vbproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\K6.Helpers\K6.Helpers.vbproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="My Project\Settings.settings">
      <CustomToolNamespace>My</CustomToolNamespace>
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Do you still have the assemblyinfo.vb file there? If that's the case, add `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>`  and delete the file (mandatory). Pre-release versions can have a suffix added to the Version. See also the `<VersionSuffix>` attribute. Configure the Projects using the `Project->Properties` tool

Comment: Thank you for your help.
That was the right hint.
There was a tag in the assemblyinfo.vb file: `<assemblyInftormationalVersionAttribute>`
which said “+79272f70694e133e533d…”.

In the vbproj file I set the tag: `<GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>`
Now the version is correct as I wanted.